# In a trigger, how to check if no fields have changed?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

If we receive an update statement that does not check if the value has changed in the where clause, what are the different ways to ignore that update inside a trigger?

I know we can do a comparison of each individual field (handling the ISNULL side as well), but where it's a table that has 50+ fields, is there a faster/easier way to do it?

Note: This could be used to reduce IO/noise in audit records etc...

**EXAMPLE**

For a table of:

```
CREATE TABLE myTest
(ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
 Field1 varchar(10) NULL,
 Field2 varchar(20) NULL)
```

with an after updater trigger containing:

```
INSERT INTO myTestAudit (ID, Field1, Field2, DateTimeUpdate)
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, getDate()
FROM inserted
```

with initial values:

```
INSERT INTO myTest (Field1, Field2)
SELECT 'a', 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'c'
```

Now run an update:

```
UPDATE myTest set Field2 = 'b' WHERE Field1 = 'a'
```

Comment: I have two questions:  Why do you want to ignore updates that don't modify anything, and more importantly why are there updates being performeed that don't modify anything?  Sound like if you filter out this data, you may be ignoring a serious problem with the application.

Comment: There are indeed problems in the application(s) where updates are being called with no changes, this creates noise on the server and does need to be cleaned up (issue has been created and queued), however the audit triggers are creating **extra** noise by writing them those changes as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bring back rows where at least one value has changed you can use

```
SELECT /*TODO: Column List*/
FROM   INSERTED I
       JOIN DELETED D
         ON I.ID = D.ID
            AND EXISTS (SELECT I.*
                        EXCEPT
                        SELECT D.*)
```

Comment: +1 interesting, do you have any info on performance and how it handles nullable values?

Comment: d'oh!  found answer on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662902/when-to-use-except-as-opposed-to-not-exists-in-transact-sql) that reports `EXCEPT` treats `NULL` values as matching, which would not work...

Comment: @AndrewBickerton - Nope. This is what you need. If both sides are `(1,NULL)` for example then you want `null` values to be treated as equal and `(1,NULL) EXCEPT (1,NULL)` to return an empty set as nothing has changed. [Some info here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

Comment: you're right (hadn't had my morning coffee!)

Answer (score 2):

Put this as the very first line in your trigger:

```
-- Exit trigger if no data was actually modified
IF (@@ROWCOUNT  = 0)  return
```

I do this in all of my audit triggers.  It is short and to the point, definitely cuts down on wasted I/O.

Update: Sorry, I misread your question.  I thought you asked how to exit the trigger if no data has changed.

Comment: we do this already (and yes it definitely helps!)..  Good advice though.

Comment: This isn't always reliable. I can't quantify when, but I have been bitten. I use `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN`

Comment: @gbn - For a `MERGE` statement `@@ROWCOUNT` contains the row count of all actions - Not just the one being handled by the specific trigger that is currently firing. Was that it?

Comment: @MartinSmith: no, before MERGE on '2000 and '2005.

Comment: In my case, we needed to exit the trigger as absolutely fast as possible.  The audit was a "nice to have" feature, but performance was still top priority (very busy server).  I wonder if there is some SQL bug somewhere that causes @@ROWCOUNT to not be properly incremented.